# How to change richTextBox's right to left type?

Tags: c#

I wanna use a right2left language in my rich text box but faced a lot of problems with bullets etc.
I want to make this

[image]

this is my problem
[image]
can sb help me?
thanks

Comment: Please write specific problem, show example for us that we could recreate that problem.

Comment: I want to load a .rft file in my app and change it's direction to right2left by clicking on a button

Comment: Just give an example text (how your rtf looks like) and how it should look like in your RTB

Comment: I finally can upload pics and edit post.What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select your richtextbox and set it's `RightToLeft` property to `Yes`

[image]

and U will get what U need.

[image]

**EDITS:**

Then, if I understand You correctly, You should parse richtextbox's RTF yourself. Using Microsoft Word I created RTF file with left formatted and right formatted texts, compared their RTF strings and made the following:

Added **openFileDialog1** control and **two buttons**

`button1` to open file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
      {
         richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
      }
}
```

and `button2` to change richtextbox's RTF string:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var indexofltrparObject = richTextBox1.Rtf.IndexOf(@"\ltrpar", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
     richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Insert(indexofltrparObject, @"\qr");
}
```

So I got **before** `button2` click:

[image]

and **after**:

[image]

Is that what You need?

**MORE EDITS**

To change text align back to **LeftToRight** just remove **"\qr"** string You have recently added to richtextbox's RTF string:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int indexOfQr = richTextBox1.Rtf.IndexOf(@"\qr", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
     if (indexOfQr != -1)
        richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Remove(indexOfQr, @"\qr".Length);
}
```

Comment: Actually I have done it before but bullets and some other things face problem when loaded file is not R2L

Comment: Thank you dear Dmytro Tsiniavsky.

Answer (score 0):

If I create an RTB I can change the style to rightToLeft.
Just set this option to yes. Hope this is what you want else tell me what you want to do in detail and i may help you ;)

Edit: Maybe you can go this way. Check every line whether the first char is a bullet. If it is true
Delete it and appent it to the other side.

Comment: I want to load a .rft file in my app and change it's direction to right2left by clicking on a button

Comment: So do you want the text to be aligned to the right side or do you want for example "hello" to be changed to "olleh" ?

Comment: no.I want to make a button like "Right-to-Left Text Direction" on "microsoft Word" on "Home" tab that can change text direction and save changes to my loaded rtf file

Answer (score 0):

change the property value of RichTextBox, [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to 'Yes'.

Comment: I have done it but bullets and some other things face problem when loaded file is not R2L

Comment: @mhc give us some example .rtf

Comment: I want to make a button like "Right-to-Left Text Direction" on "microsoft Word" on "Home" tab that can change text direction and save changes to my loaded rtf file